# How to fix a div to the same side when a mobile is on landscape

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

In my mobile app I have a bar which is fixed to the bottom of the app when the device is on portrait.

And when on landscape it should be moved and fixed to the side instead of the bottom of the screen.

Now I can do this with media queries by changing the displays and widths and positioning. But my problem is, the bar should always be fixed to the side where the home button on the mobile is.

Here is what I want to achieve,
[image]

- If a user tilts the phone to the left - The bar is fixed to the
  right.
- If a user tilts the phone to the right - The bar is fixed to the
  left.

I'm using Angular 2 and Ionic 2.

Can you please tell me how to implement such a behaviour. A pure **CSS, angular** solution would be great.

Comment: I'm still learning on this field. Does this can be achieved through `screen.orientation.angle` ?

Comment: Maybe this coudl help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation
But I doubt you'de be able to detect Landscape left/Right... CSS properties look at the dpi and screen size to determine orientation

Comment: What about upside-down portrait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS Solution**

It doesn't seem like there is a pure CSS way to do it. In theory, you should be able to dynamically add/remove the appropriate CSS classes via some JS that listens to device orientation changes, though. You could use class names like `portrait`, `landscape-left`, and `landscape-right` and add them to `<body>`. See below for my code sample or try it out at [this code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjZEbw) (note that it only changes color of a div, but I'm sure you can figure out the proper CSS from there):

JS:

```
function clearOrientationClasses() {
    document.body.classList.remove('portrait-up');
    document.body.classList.remove('landscape-left');
    document.body.classList.remove('portrait-down');
    document.body.classList.remove('landscape-right');
}

function handleOrientation(event) {
    var alpha = event.alpha;

    // Up
    if(alpha <= 45 || alpha > 315) {
        clearOrientationClasses();
        document.body.classList.add('portrait-up');

    // Left
    } else if (alpha > 45 && alpha <= 135) {
        clearOrientationClasses();
        document.body.classList.add('landscape-left');

    // Down
    } else if (alpha > 135 && alpha <= 225) {
        clearOrientationClasses();
        document.body.classList.add('portrait-down');

    // Right
    } else {
        clearOrientationClasses();
        document.body.classList.add('landscape-right');
    }
}

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
```

CSS:

```
.portrait-up .menu { ... }
.portrait-down .menu { ... }
.landscape-left .menu { ... }
.landscape-right .menu { ... }
```

[More info on Device Orientation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation)

**Media Queries**

The above approach would not be supported on all browsers/devices, though. Media queries like `@media (orientation: portrait) { ... }` and `@media (orientation: landscape) { ... }`can be used to partially fill the gap, but these do not provide you with a means to place your menu on the left or the right as you would like.

I recommend using media queries to always place on one particular side where Device Orientation isn't supported...or just change your project requirements in light of this limitation.

Again, [more info at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation)

**Additional Notes:**
The JS above is probably not the most efficient. It may benefit from a de-bouncing function or some other similar performance enhancement.